# Why doesn't the for loop increment?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, heap-memory

Why doesn't my for-loop increment? The Integer "i" doesn't increment somehow and that results the first position of the array to be printed out.

I do the following:

```cpp
int* values = new int[10] {};

int& half(int* arr[]){

  //Here, the "i" doesn't increment  

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      return *arr[i];
  }
}

int main(){
   int& a = half(&values);
   std::cout << a << std::endl;

   delete[] values;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you expected this code to do. Print out every element of the array?

Comment: @Kevin The thing is... my main objective is different. I know, for just printing every element of array i could do very different things and very short and precise things that will achieve the same goal. But I just wanted to mesh up with everything I have and learn that way.

Comment: @OkanGüclü The function returns when `i` is 0. C++ returns don't accumulate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` statement causes a function to immediately exit with the specified value. As a result, when you execute the statement

```
return *arr[i];
```

inside of your loop, the function will stop running and return the indicated value. This means that the loop can't execute multiple times, since it'll stop running after the very first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

for what you are trying to do, you should add the values from your for loop to an array and return that list:

```
    int newValues[10] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       newValues[i] = i;
    }
    return newVaules;
```

Comment: I fixed the initialization line.

Answer (score 0):

the root of your problem is `return` statement . If you call it - your function will end its work with value passed to return. 
Second thing - you're doing some unecessary work with pointers and refereneces - Perhaps you might forgot that name of array is a reference to its first element.

And the third thing : As there's and usage of references, pointers, references , array and functions , but in some confusing way - I'm guessing that code is some kind of way to learn those things - If so , you can write in comments - what you want from your code to do and in what way? - So I or other users could help you learn and understand how to do it in proper way

Comment: Thank you for your comment too. Yes, that code is some kind of way to learn things. I am definitely gonna consider your opinion as well.